# how to use 'presentViewController' with cover View and main page

Tags: swift, ios9, presentviewcontroller

A lots app, they have the cover view, like facebook, wechat...
but when I try to use presentViewController let the cover present to main page, that still in the cover vie. The following is my code:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var coverVC:CoverView?
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        coverVC = ViewController()
        coverVC?.refresh(window!.frame)
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

Coverview

```
class CoverView: UIViewController {

func refresh(frame:CGRect){
    self.view.frame = frame
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    var mainVC:mainView = mainView()
    mainVC.refresh(frame)

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

    self.presentViewController(mainVC, animated: false, completion: nil)       
   }
}
```

Main view:

```
class mainView: UIViewController {

        func refresh(frame:CGRect){
             self.view.frame = frame
             self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        }
}
```

Maybe can use other easy way to achieve the goal, that's ok.
otherwise, please don't use "UInavigationcontroller", I know that can present view, but I don't want the bar in cover view, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find the correct with cover/login view, it is called SplashScreen.
And in xcode 9, you can find at [TARGETS]>[APP icons and Launch Images]  ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsQ3Y.png)).(The past version, you need add "launch image" in plist file.)

Otherwise, If you doesn't want use this view, just delete "LaunchScreen".